# Which folder to store design files in Rails App?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, file

I have a few other files related to my Rails website I am building like a few wireframes, mocks, and other design files. I want to store them in the Rails website directory so that all the things relating to that project are in the same folder. Where should I store these non-essential, non-related files inside a Rails app? Public/, Lib/, Vendor/? Please help me out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want them to be easily accessible, use public/. Otherwise, I would suggest just creating a new directory for these things, design/ perhaps.